# Rcpp in markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, rcpp

I'm trying to use a function created using `Rcpp` package within Rmarkdown document. But the following results in an error:

````
```{Rcpp firstChunk}
Rcpp::IntegerVector doubleMe(Rcpp::IntegerVector x) {
  return x + x;
}
```
````

> C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -I"C:/Users/JAKMIC~1/DOCUME~1/R/R-35~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"C:/Users/jakmicha1/Documents/R/R-3.5.1/library/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/jakmicha1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQBQexm/sourceCpp-x86_64-w64-mingw32-0.12.18"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c file17ec52d61f75.cpp -o file17ec52d61f75.o
>   file17ec52d61f75.cpp:1:1: error: 'Rcpp' does not name a type
>    Rcpp::IntegerVector doubleMe(Rcpp::IntegerVector x) {
>    ^
>   make: *** [C:/Users/JAKMIC~1/DOCUME~1/R/R-35~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf:215: file17ec52d61f75.o] Error 1
>   Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = "Rcpp::IntegerVector doubleMe(Rcpp::IntegerVector x) {\n  return x + x;\n}") : 
>     Error 1 occurred building shared library.

What may be a cause and how can I solve it?

#### Edit:

Thanks for all the replies. The code seems to work ok while running chunks. There is an error while knitting though.

````
---
title: "title"
output: pdf_document
---

```{Rcpp firstChunk}
#include <Rcpp.h>

//[[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector double2Me(Rcpp::IntegerVector x) {
  return x + x;
}
```

```{r callFirstChunkInR}
double2Me(c(2, 2))
```
# In command 'system(cmd)': 'make' not found

# Quitting from lines 7-13 (title.Rmd) 
# Error in command '(function (file = "", code = NULL, env = globalenv(), embeddedR = TRUE, ':
#  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
# Calls: <Anonymous> ... block_exec -> in_dir -> engine -> do.call -> <Anonymous>
````

I'm using Rmarkdown 1.10 within RStudio 1.1.456 on Windows 7 and Rcpp_0.12.19. Any ideas?

Comment: You missed a few thousand live examples out there, including (of course) at the Rcpp Gallery which runs off Rcpp code examples written in Rmarkdown.

Comment: You need to install Rtools 3.5 in the default location `C:/Rtools`, c.f. http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/installing-rtools-for-compiled-code-via-rcpp/

Comment: I already have it installed there.

Comment: Make sure that the values the `Rtools` tries to insert on your path are at the beginning then.

Answer (score 4):

You have to `#include <Rcpp>` in your code chunk, and most likely, add the `// [[Rcpp:export]]` directive to your function as well.

Like this:

````
```{Rcpp firstChunk}
#include <Rcpp.h>

//[[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector doubleMe(Rcpp::IntegerVector x) {
  return x + x;
}
```
````

Comment: Thanks. It does work while running a chunk, but not while knitting. I have edited my post with a returned error.

Answer (score 4):

The Rcpp chunks in R-markdown are equivalent to `Rcpp::sourceCpp`, not to `Rcpp:cppFunction`. You therefore have to specify the necessary includes and tell Rcpp to export the function:

````
```{Rcpp firstChunk}
#include <Rcpp.h>
//[[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector doubleMe(Rcpp::IntegerVector x) {
  return x + x;
}
```
````

Comment: Thanks. It does work while running a chunk, but not while knitting. I have edited my post with a returned error.

Comment: @jakes Please provide a [mcve] for this new error message.

Comment: I have edited with whole document. Don't know if it's relevant, but I'm using Rmarkdown in Rstudio

Comment: @jakes Your example document runs fine for me (Debian Linux, R 3.5.1, RStudio 1.2.907, Rcpp 0.12.19, rmarkdown 1.10).

Comment: I use Windows 7, RStudio 1.1.456, the rest is the same. Maybe is something wrong due to Windows?

Answer (score 4):

You just omitted the inclusion of the `Rcpp.h` and the `[[Rcpp::export]]` attribute to create and link the function into *R*.

````
```{Rcpp firstChunk}
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector doubleMe(Rcpp::IntegerVector x) {
  return x + x;
}
```
````

In another chunk, you can call the Rcpp function with the engine
*R*.

````
```{r callFirstChunkInR}
doubleMe(c(2, 2))
```
````

Additional information on using different engines in R Markdown documents can be found at:

[R Markdown: The Definitive Guide - Chapter 2, Section 2.7 Other language engines](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html)

#### Examples with Rcpp in R Markdown

You can find some of my previous `so` answer RMarkdown files that use `Rcpp` here:

https://github.com/coatless/so

#### Render of RMarkdown Document

[image]

Comment: Pretty loud document with the large font but takes the answer home.  Good idea with the SO repo too.

Comment: macOS Retina display greatly increased the size of the screenshot... I've tweaked it now.

Comment: Thanks. It does work while running a chunk, but not while knitting. I have edited my post with a returned error.

Answer (score 1):

I have a related problem, which seems to be caused by the default chunk header inserted by RStudio Ver 1.1.442 for Rcpp chunks in an RMarkdown file.

Borrowing from the OPs question above, this doesn't work:

````
```{rcpp firstChunk}
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// Function declaration with export tag
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector doubleMe(Rcpp::IntegerVector x) {
  return x + x;
}
```
````

RStudio produces the following error message when I attempt to run the chunk:

> 'rcpp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

However, this works fine:

````
```{Rcpp firstChunk}
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// Function declaration with export tag
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector doubleMe(Rcpp::IntegerVector x) {
  return x + x;
}
```
````

The only difference between the two pieces of code are "Rcpp" and "rcpp" in the chunk headers.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21704669)

Comment: @drhagen - agreed, it doesn't specifically answer the OPs question, but it is related, and provides some guidance for anyone who comes to SO looking for pointers on why they get an ambiguous message about Rcpp chunks in Rmd's. Also, when I looked last week, there wasn't a question specifically related to the one I had, this one was closest, and in the meantime, I've solved my own problem - putting the solution here for others to benefit.